# I got the translation from googletrans working in Python but want to pull just the translated text to make it easier to read, any advice?

Tags: python, python-3.x, translation, google-translate

so I got a basic CLI python translator to function, now I need help pulling just the translated text from the result.

This is my current code

```html
from googletrans import Translator

# Taking input for language to be translated
translate_from = input("What language would you like to translate from? ")
translate_to = input("What language would you like to translate to? ")

# Taking input for text to be translated
translate_text = input("Please enter your text to be translated ... ")

# translate languages
translator=Translator()

print("Translation > ", translator.translate(translate_text, src=translate_from, dest=translate_to))
```

This is the current output:

> Translation >  Translated(src=en, dest=es, text=Hola, pronunciation=None, extra_data="{'translat...")

I would like it to just pull the text only instead of the above. Can anyone help me on this because I am pretty stumped!

Also I am very new to Python, so please go easy on me!

Answer (score 0):

[`translator.translate`](https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans/blob/master/googletrans/client.py#L121) [returns](https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans/blob/master/googletrans/client.py#L139) a [`Translated`](https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans/blob/master/googletrans/models.py#L9) instance. It stores translated text in its `.text` property. So,

```
translation = translator.translate(...)
print("Translation > ", translation.text)
```

Or, when a list of strings was passed for translation,

```
translations = translator.translate([string1, string2, ...], ...)
for translation in translations:
    print("Translation > ", translation.text)
```